# Scroll to bottom of div with smooth scroll

Tags: javascript

I have a container and I have a function using `scrollTop` that will scroll to the bottom of the container when it is called.

```
function updateScroll(){
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("con-result");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
};
```

How do I add smooth scrolling functionality to this? I know that there is `behavior: smooth` available but I don't know how to add this to what i'm trying to do as it is available using window.scrollTo().

Comment: Did you try [the CSS property `scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) for it?

Comment: Consider using [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#behavior) or [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo#behavior) and pass the behaviour with the value 'smooth' to the options object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using directly CSS you can use `element.scroll()` by setting its top property to `element.scrollHeight`. like this:

```
   objDiv.scroll({ top: objDiv.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Or you can also use `element.scrollIntoView()`, and setting its parameter to false, which aligns the element at the bottom of the viewport:

```
   let aDiv = document.getElementById("con-resul");
   aDiv .scrollIntoView(false);
```

Lastly you can use JQuery, with `animate()`:

```
   let objDiv = $("#con-result");
   objDiv.stop().animate({ scrollTop: objDiv.prop("scrollHeight") }, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this

```
#con-result {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

function updateScroll(){
   var objDiv = document.getElementById("con-result");
   // No change needed here, the CSS will take care of the smooth behavior
   objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
};
```

Set the scroll behavior before calling updateScroll

```
document.getElementById("con-result").style.scrollBehavior = "smooth";
```

Call this function whenever you want to scroll

```
updateScroll();
```

Answer (score 1):

To scroll to the bottom of the element you can use `scrollTo()` along with the `behaviour: smooth` property:

```js
function scrollToBottom(el) {
  el.scrollTo({
    top: el.scrollHeight,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
};

const targetElement = document.querySelector('#con-result');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => scrollToBottom(targetElement));
```

```css
#con-result {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#con-result>div {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<button>Scroll down</button>
<div id="con-result">
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add smooth scrolling functionality to the scrollTop assignment in JavaScript, you can't directly use the behavior: smooth option since that's part of the scrollTo options object available in the newer Scroll API, which doesn't apply to the scrollTop property.

However, you can achieve a smooth scrolling effect by using `Element.scrollIntoView()` with behavior: 'smooth', or by using the newer scrollTo with the appropriate options if you're targeting modern browsers.

Here's how you could do it using `scrollIntoView():`

```
function updateScroll(){
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("con-result");
    var scrollHeight = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    var scrollToEnd = document.createElement("div");
    
    scrollToEnd.style.position = 'absolute';
    scrollToEnd.style.top = scrollHeight + 'px';
    objDiv.appendChild(scrollToEnd);

    scrollToEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    
    // Optional: Remove the div after the scroll, if you want to keep the DOM clean
    scrollToEnd.remove();
};
```

And here is how you could do it using the scrollTo with the top property set to scrollHeight:

```
function updateScroll(){
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("con-result");
    objDiv.scrollTo({
        top: objDiv.scrollHeight,
        behavior: 'smooth    });
};
```

Both of these methods will add a smooth scrolling animation to your container. Keep in mind that scrollIntoView and the options object for scrollTo may not be supported in all browsers, especially older ones. Always check for compatibility if you expect your website to be used on older browsers or consider polyfills for broader support.

Also, if you're dynamically adding content to the container and want to scroll to the bottom as new content is added, make sure to call updateScroll after the new content has been appended to ensure accurate scrolling.

Comment: [ChatGPT is banned at SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)